# How not to call clean method in django model when editing?

Tags: django

I have a model called LeaseTerm .I want not to have more than 1 leaseTerm per specific Lease that is is_active and not is_terminated

```
 class LeaseTerm(CommonInfo):
        version = IntegerVersionField( )
        start_period = models.ForeignKey(Period, related_name='start_period' )
        end_period = models.ForeignKey(Period, related_name='end_period')
        lease = models.ForeignKey(Lease)
        increase  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
        amount  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
        is_terminated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        def clean(self):
            model = self.__class__
            if self.lease_id and (self.is_terminated == False) and model.objects.filter(lease=self.lease, is_active=True ).count() == 1:
                raise ValidationError('!Lease has a active condition already, Terminate prior to creation of new one'.format(self.lease))
```

For this I wrote a clean method that works perfectly when I create a new lease term. However this method is a problem when I do Edit since it counts itself and not allowing to save .

Any recommendation how can I overcome this problem? I just want to skip the clean method when I edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just exclude the current LeaseTerm instance from your query? That way the .clean() method is still useful if you need to do something with it later.

It would just be a matter of adding `.exclude(id=self.id)` to the queryset.

i.e.

`model.objects.filter(lease=self.lease, is_active=True ).exclude(id=self.id).count()`